Image not displaying when using the GET method in Flutter
I'm facing an issue with displaying an image in my Flutter application when using the GET method to fetch it from a URL. Here's the relevant code snippet:
Positioned(
  top: 90,
  left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 87) / 2,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: getImage,
    child: ClipOval(
      child: Container(
        width: 87,
        height: 87,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 3,
          ),
        ),
        child: _imageFile != null
            ? Image.file(
                _imageFile!,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
            : (_profilData != null &&
                    _profilData!['image'] != null)
                ? CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        'http://172.16.103.5/flutter/foto_profil/${_profilData!['image']}',
                    placeholder: (context, url) =>
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        Icon(Icons.error),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                : Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/icon_profil.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),


The issue I'm encountering is that the image does not display when using CachedNetworkImage from the flutter_cache_manager package. Instead, I only see the placeholder or error widget.
I have verified that the URL is correct and the image exists at that location. Could someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Try to place your actual image url in imageUrl without _profilData['image'] and check if working or not.
Use CachedNetworkImage from cached_network_image package.
